# Is there any difference between 'input' and 'conditional input' in the case of neural networks?

Tags: generative-adversarial-networks, notation, input-layer, conditional-probability, conditional-gan

In the research paper titled [Conditional Generative Adversarial Nets](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.1784.pdf) by *Mehdi Mirza and Simon Osindero*, there is a notion of conditioning a neural network on a class label.

It is mentioned in the abstract that we need to **simply** feed extra input $y$ to the generator and discriminator of an unconditional GAN.

> Generative Adversarial Nets were recently introduced as a novel
> way to train generative models. In this work we introduce the
> conditional version of generative adversarial nets, which can be
> **constructed by simply feeding the data, $y$, we wish to condition on to
> both the generator and discriminator.** We show that this model can
> generate MNIST digits conditioned on class labels. We also illustrate
> how this model could be used to learn a multi-modal model, and provide
> preliminary examples of an application to image tagging in which we
> demonstrate how this approach can generate descriptive tags which are
> not part of training labels.

So, I cannot see whether there is any special treatment for input $y$.

If there is no special treatment for the data $y$, then why do they call $y$ a condition and follow the notation of conditional probability such as $G(z|y), D(x|y)$ instead of $G(z,y), D(x,y)$?

If there is a special treatment to input $y$, then what is that special? Don't they pass $y$ in the same way as $x$ to the neural networks?

Comment: Normally data is *not* fed to both the generator and the discriminator, so isn't that already a special treatment?

Comment: @user253751 yeah true. In general $z$ is the only input to generator and $x$ or $G(z)$  is the actual input to discriminator. Please answer it if you are sure that $y$ has no difference in treatment as $z$ for generator and $y$ has no difference in treatment as $x$ or $G(z)$ for discriminator. But, how would they pass $y$ is another doubt in my question.  Will they pass normally? Suppose $z=[1, 2, 3, 4]$ and $y = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]$ then what can be the actual input for $G$?

Comment: @user253751 why can't they use $G(z, y)$ instead of  $G(z/y)$ etc.,?

Comment: they can, or they can not. It's their choice since they are the ones writing the letters.